# Где хранить документацию и вспомогательные файлы проекта?

Tags: git, github, документация

Где хранить документацию и вспомогательные файлы, которые не относятся к коду, например, скриншоты для README.md?

По скриншотам нашел два ответа на enSO:

- [How to add screenshot to READMEs in github repository ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189356/how-to-add-screenshot-to-readmes-in-github-repository)
- [Add images to README.md on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Но там больше затрагивается проблема оформления README.md через Markdown. Меня же интересуют лучшие практики для хранения вспомогательных данных. Какое место выбрать для хранения? Отдельная ветка или репозиторий? Как использовать эти вспомогательные данные?

Пока вижу для себя следующее решение. Создаю в проекте ветку с вспомогательными данными и кладу туда скриншоты, а к ним уже обращаюсь из файла README.md.

Для документации ситуация аналогична; думаю, пока проект небольшой, доки могут храниться в одном репозитории.

Сам сейчас использую GitLab/GitHub.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим опытом.

Comment: из одной ветки ссылаться на другую - это чревато проблемами. например, вы случайно можете удалить ветку или переименовать.

Comment: мне такой подход нравится: создаёте для документации отдельный сайт на GitHub Pages — это бесплатно — и туда выкладываете документацию для всех своих проектов. Можно воспользоваться генераторами статических сайтов, написанными специально для документаций, вроде [**MkDocs**](http://www.mkdocs.org/). Преимущество в том, что в HTML намного больше возможностей для оформления, чем в `.md` файлах GitHub. Спасибо.

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы ответ про конфлюенс приняли?

Comment: @СашаЧерных поддерживаю вашу точку зрения. Только не совсем понятно, вы предлагаете сразу в HTML писать из-за того, что Markdown ограничен? Если так, то пожалуйста, прочитайте [Why we need constrainable lightweight markup languages](http://everypageispageone.com/2016/06/05/why-we-need-constrainable-lightweight-markup-languages/). Но вообще GitHub вам показывает readme не в Md, а отрендеренным в HTML – то есть вы в любом случае видите возможности оформления из HTML.

Comment: @NickVolynkin о, это было больше 3 месяцев назад. я много не знал, учился и применял новые знания на практике. на тот момент мне был ближе и, на мой взгляд, разумнее этот ответ. тем более в моем нынешнем проекте используется конфлюенс. это решение удобно для корпоративных проектов. но теперь понимаю, что для как для коммерческого, так и опенсорсного кода разумно использовать документацию на отдельном сайте - [ответ](https://goo.gl/Ah2fRT) @ СашаЧерных .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное самое лучшее решение иметь confluence, а так же хранить проект либо на bitbuckete(jira), либо tfs, если windows разработка, там очень мощные возможности вести документацию и хранить  вспомогательные файлы

Comment: спасибо, но я бы не хотел привязываться к какой-то технологии или системе, а найти универсальное решение. сам сейчас использую gitlab/github.

Comment: Пока вижу для себя следующее решение. Создаю в проекте ветку с вспомогательными данными и кладу туда скриншоты, а к ним уже обращаюсь из файла README.md.

Для документации ситуация аналогична, думаю, пока проект небольшой, доки могут храниться в одном репозитории.

Comment: @while1pass, я думаю главная задача jira и есть универсальность, вряд ли кто то сделает лучше.

Comment: `самое лучшее решение иметь confluence` – как технический писатель вам говорю — нет, далеко не лучшее решение. Устаревшее лет на 10, требующее сервера, денег на лицензию и обслуживающего админа.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Даже не знаю, что вам ответить. Наверно раз вас волнует платный сервер вашего проекта он не очень успешен, у меня таких проблем нет, все очень удобно и постоянно под рукой. Возможно это моё субъективное мнение.

Comment: @YuryBakharev множество проектов — опенсорсные и любительские, у них нет бюджета на конфлюенс. Расшифрую "устаревшее лет на 10": представьте, что вам предлагают программировать в Word и сохранять код в БД. Согласитесь? Вот конфлюенс это то же самое для документации. Нет нормального версионирования, нет веток, нет нормальной среды разработки, нельзя или трудно задеплоить в тестовое окружение, трудно обрабатывать тексты программным кодом.

Comment: А еще в конфлюенсе есть одна публичная версия, на которую можно смотреть. И линейная история разработки каждого документа. Если вы хотите подготовить большой объем новой документации и потом его выпустить (например, вместе с мажорным релизом документируемого продукта), то с конфлюенсом это будет очень сложно.

Answer (score 11):

Хранить документацию (скриншоты и диаграммы относятся к ней) лучше в той же ветке, что и код. Например, в отдельно директории в корне проекта диретория **docs**. Чем "ближе" документация к коду, тем меньше вероятность расхождения кода и документации.

Для многих фреймворков и систем сборки существуют правила хранение документации к коду. Например, **maven** ожидает, что у вас будет директория **site** и в ней будет документация и тогда **maven** сможет её отформатировать и загрузить на сайт.

Так же многие фреймворки могут выдавать ошибки, если к коду отсутствует документация.

Существуют различные плагины к системам сборки которые помогают создавать, проверять и публиковать документацию. Например, **AsciiDoctor** имеет плагины для различных систем сборки.

Comment: Так получается, что у нас разбухает основная ветка master, и мы тащим доки и скришоты в локальный репозиторий при клонировании. Разве это разумно?

Comment: я дописал в вопросе возможное на мой взгляд решение - создать отдельную ветку для доков и данных проекта. Такой подход возможен?

Comment: Да это разумно - хранить все в одной ветке. Если у вас очень большие бинарные файлы, то стоит воспользоваться LFS. Если вы поместите документацию в отдельную ветку, то ее никто не будет обновлять.

Answer (score 4):

Если документация - это отдельный проект, который разрабатывается отдельными людьми и никак реально не связан с кодом -- то стоит завести отдельный репозиторий.

Так например делает github, создавая под wiki вполне самостоятельный репозиторий, которым можно отдельно управлять и вести историю изменений.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Мнение

Подход, который мне больше всего нравится — **создание для документации отдельного сайта**. Так делают разработчики Open Source проектов, которые мне представляются наиболее серьёзными и значимыми.

Это можно осуществить бесплатно, если пользоваться [**генераторами статических сайтов**](http://prgssr.ru/development/pochemu-generatory-staticheskih-sajtov-budut-populyarny.html).

---

### 2. Примеры документаций, сделанных при помощи средств, помогающих размещать их на отдельных сайтах

1. [**MkDocs**](http://www.mkdocs.org/) — [**пример**](http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/usage/)

[image: MkDocs]

2. [**ReadTheDocs**](https://readthedocs.org/) — [**пример**](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

[image: ReadTheDocs]

3. [**Sphinx**](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) — [**некоторые проекты, использующие Sphinx**](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.0/examples.html); [**пример**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html):

[image: Sphinx]

---

### 3. Аргументы

Основной аргумент — ограничения хостингов для размещения HTML-сайтов ниже тех, с которыми приходится иметь дело при размещении документации на BitBucket, GitHub (но не с [**BitBucket Pages**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html), [**GitHub Pages**](https://pages.github.com/)), GitLab и аналогичных ресурсах.

Положим, если Вы решили разместить документацию в `README.MD` и прочих `.md` файлах на GitHub:

#### 3.1 Доступно

1. Всё, что [**позволено разметкой Markdown**](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax),

   **но**

   не то что в Markdown достигается средствами HTML, а не самого Markdown.

   Упрощённо говоря, Вы можете использовать чёрный по белому текст, изображения, таблицы, но не более того.

#### 3.2 Недоступно

1. [**Не получится использовать JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340902/5951529): Вы не сможете использовать JQuery-плагины, сделать удобное меню на Bootstrap для удобства перемещения пользователей по Вашей документации, вынуждены будете отказывать себе в мелочах вроде [**кастомного скроллбара**](http://noeldelgado.github.io/gemini-scrollbar/) и т. д.
2. [**Не получится встроить видео**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945782/5951529) без перехода на другую страницу для его просмотра.

---

### 4. Особенности генераторов статических сайтов

1. Писать сайты прямо в HTML не очень удобно. К счастью, одной из функций генераторов статических сайтов является рендеринг текста, написанного в удобной для Вас разметке, как то Markdown или [**reStructuredText**](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), непосредственно в HTML.
2. Возможность интеграции с инструментами для сборки: я, допустим, использую Pelican + Grunt + CoffeeScript + Stylus.
3. Существуют генераторы, специально ориентированные для написания документаций к проектам. Некоторые примеры приведены в разделе 2. Притом если Вас устраивают уже имеющиеся темы, можно использовать их, а не писать с нуля.

---

### 5. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Static Site Generators**](http://www.oreilly.com/web-platform/free/static-site-generators.csp) — бесплатная книга издательства O'Reilly,
- [**Working with Static sites**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920051879.do),
- [**Альтернативы MkDocs на AlternativeTo.Net**](http://alternativeto.net/software/mkdocs/).

Comment: Я поддерживаю этот подход и только что написал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691633/181472) практически о том же. Поправлю пару моментов: ReadTheDocs под капотом использует Sphinx; ограничения хостингов не фатальны, можно хостить самостоятельно; JavaScript использовать получится.

Comment: Ну и «Писать сайты прямо в HTML не очень удобно» — это вообще не проблема. Основная функция генератора — создавать HTML из текста, написанного в разметке. Никто не пишет сырой HTML, разве что в шаблонах и уникальных элементах сайта с документацией (например, брендированная шапка).

Comment: И вообще вы как будто свели этот подход к хранению .md на гитхабе, хотя сами используете гораздо более продвинутый набор с Pelican и остальным.

Comment: Но в целом (что-то я накритиковал много) плюс вам и спасибо, что продвигаете этот подход.

Comment: @NickVolynkin♦: `поправлю пару моментов` — под «поправкой» понимаю [**исправление каких-либо ошибок в тексте; дополнение, которое исправляет, изменяет что-либо**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/3913/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0). Т. е., насколько понял, вы с чем-то не согласны, что-то оспариваете, а не «согласны, но дополняете». Только я не понял, с чем. Если же не оспариваете, то что хотели Вы показать своими комментариями?

Comment: Очень желательно, если элементом оспорения является `объект оспорения` — слова, фразы, выражения и т. п. оппонента, которые подвергаются оспорению. Игнорирование данного условия в жизни подчас приводит к тому, что тот, кто оспаривает, оспаривает совсем не то, что выражено тем, кого оспаривают. В ваших комментариях отсутствует объект оспорения.

Comment: К конкретике. `ReadTheDocs под капотом использует Sphinx` — разве писал обратное?

Comment: `можно хостить самостоятельно; JavaScript использовать получится` — поясню п. 3 другими словами. Проблемы с JavaScript и ограничениями возникают, если размещать документации на самих GitLab/BitBucket/GitLab, **не создавая сайт**. Вопрос: точно ли «можно хостить самостоятельно» и «получится использовать JavaScript» в таком случае, без создания сайта?

Comment: `ограничения хостингов не фатальны` — где я писал обратное?

Comment: `Ну и «Писать сайты прямо в HTML не очень удобно» — это вообще не проблема. Основная функция генератора — создавать HTML из текста, написанного в разметке. Никто не пишет сырой HTML, разве что в шаблонах и уникальных элементах сайта с документацией (например, брендированная шапка)` — об этом и написал другими словами в п. 4.1.

Comment: `И вообще вы как будто свели этот подход к хранению .md на гитхабе, хотя сами используете гораздо более продвинутый набор с Pelican и остальным.` — не понимаю посылки, на основании которых было выдвинуто данное оценочное заключение. Этим же пунктом 4.2 ответа я как раз попытался показать, что нет, не сводится.

Comment: И [**отменил**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/686957/3) вашу правку в предложении `Существуют генераторы, специально ориентированные для написания документаций к проектам.` Употребил слово `документации` во множественном числе, поскольку не одна же документация на все проекты, — для каждого проекта своя документация. Если считаете, что мои действия некорректны, пожалуйста, оставьте пояснения. Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, что в данном случае «документация» — неисчислимое. Сравните: «нож для резки сыра», но не «сыров», «комбайн для сбора урожая», но не «урожаев».