# В чем писать документацию сис.админа

Tags: windows, администрирование, документация

Добрый день.

До этого администратором не работал. Пришел в фирму, прошлый админ передал пароли и свалил (был приходящий), ни о какой карты сети, документации по сервисам речи нет. Хочется все систематизировать, инвентаризировать и задокументировать. Денег на ПО руководство, конечно, не выделяет.  Все под виндой. Что посоветуете? Смотрю в сторону вики движка, но как такового сервера нет - развернуть его негде. Есть общая папка на диске у директора, а разворачивать на своем инстансе в облаке не очень хочется.  Что посоветуете?

И может есть дельные примеры документации?

Comment: html, Text maker (Soft maker) или WPS office

Comment: с тем же успехом можно использовать libreoOffice, только потом при экспорте выглядит страшно, и почти никак не поддерживается. Я уже не говорю про оглавления, ссылки, и схемы

Comment: В Libre полно ошибок и падает. А зачем тебе идеальную документацию? Ну можешь ещё TEX использовать если нужно идеально.

Comment: ну если делать, то так, чтобы не стыдно показать. Плюс ко всему опыта у меня нет, а так сразу будет видно, что излишне, а что необходимо. Буду пробовать TEX, вроде подходит, но 5 гигов на установку смущают

Comment: Также можешь использовать LaTex

Comment: Лично я пишу в dokuwiki. Почти всем устраивает.

Comment: Расскажите, что у вас в итоге получилось с документацией?

Answer (score 2):

Пишите документацию в легковесном формате разметки и используйте генератор статических сайтов.

Например, этот ответ написан в легковесной разметке Markdown. Stack Exchange преобразует его в HTML, используя какой-то генератор, работающий с Markdown (таких много).

С помощью  генератора вы будете получать из исходников готовый сайт с документацией (то есть набор html + css + js + картинки). Если понадобится, то получите pdf, docx, epub, chm, manpages и остальное.

### Инструменты

Для написания документации понадобится:

- Текстовый редактор или среда разработки. Есть редакторы и плагины к средам разработки, которые сразу показывают вам результат.
- Установленный язык программирования Python или Ruby (в зависимости от выбранного формата разметки). Программировать не придётся.

Самые популярные форматы разметки:

- [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) (генераторы [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), [MkDocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/), пример: [исходники](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnet), [результат](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/))
- [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) (генератор [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/ru/stable/), специальный хостинг [Read The Docs](http://readthedocs.io/), пример: [исходники](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/index.rst), [результат](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html))
- [AsciiDoc](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/what-is-asciidoc/) (генератор [AsciiDoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/))

Я предпочитаю reStructured Text + Sphinx: разметка богаче, расширяемый, легко встраивать диаграммы [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/), любимый мной язык Python.

Рекомендую почитать слайды, которые я готовил для доклада на конференции ITGM 10: [Docs like code. Работаем с документацией, как с программным кодом.](http://nick.volynkin.gitlab.io/itgm10/#/)

### Ресурсы и инфраструктура для документации

Стоимость всего необходимого ПО нулевая.

Сайт с вашей документацией будет доступен как минимум локально, на вашей машине. Вы сможете опубликовать его на любой машине с веб-сервером (nginx или IIS, например) и парой мегабайт свободного места (вы нескоро напишете даже 1МБ документации). Вам не понадобится тратить серверные ресурсы на БД, вики-движок и прочее.

Резервное копирование документации будет очень простым: ваша документация — это текст, который легко версионируется с помощью git или любой другой системы контроля версий. Если в компании нет своего git-репозитория, вы можете завести бесплатный аккаунт на gitlab.com или bitbucket.org и создать приватный (закрытый) репозиторий там.