# Для чего ипользуют ветку gh-pages?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Для чего создают branch gh-pages? Вижу часто во многих репах на github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Github позволяет выступать как хостинг для ваших проектов. Часто это статические сайты, данные (исходники) которых находятся прямо в репозитории, рядом с исходниками проекта (или нет).

[Как создать сайт проекта с помощью gh-pages.](https://gist.github.com/saranyan/3172161)

Comment: т. е. документация обычно?

Comment: Почему не в основной ветке?

Comment: Далеко необязательно. Например, симпатичная сайт-визитка о том, что представляет собой ваш проект.

Comment: @FORTRAN так устроен github. К тому же в основной ветке должен быть сам проект, а сайту лучше находиться в независимой ветке, которая никому не мешает.

Comment: а автосгенирированую документацию куда лучше класть(javadoc к примеру)?

Comment: @FORTRAN я думаю, этот вопрос заслуживает отдельного обсуждения. Если вы определено затрудняетесь, то создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @approximatenumber кстати, я не согласен, что документации (или сайту) лучше быть в независимой ветке. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634909/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, документации для разработчиков, естественно, лучше быть в главной ветке, например, при поиске bisect'ом это позволит сразу увидеть не только изменения, но и их смысл. А вот внешний сайт лучше держать отдельно. Я в эту ветку регулярно merge'ил master, с удалением всех исходников, чтобы и связь не терялась и лишнего в ветке не было.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов а что было на этом внешнем сайте? Landing page проекта?

Comment: @FORTRAN автосгенерированная — это же артефакт сборки, так же как скомпилированные файлы. Ее незачем версионировать, можно просто деплоить на сайт с документацией. Ну и на своей машине читать. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, собственно весь сайт нашего сервиса, т. ч. и артефакты сборки. Git использовался и как инструмент деплойя (не надо в меня тухлые помидоры кидать, иногда так можно). При ошибках, выявленных уже на боевом сервере, откат до предыдущей стабильной версии производился за пару минут. И из-за некоторых особенностей бизнеса, иногда, правки приходилось делать прямо на боевом сервере, с git'ом было удобно забирать эти правки обратно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Всё зависит от кейса. Каждому проекту свой workflow ;)